# How do I get the values of this NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an incoming dictionary that looks as follows:
(this is updated)

```
{
"StationFavorites.plist" =     {
    "Addison Road" =         {
        Code = G03;
        Lat = "38.8867478168";
        Line = BL;
        Lon = "-76.89410791";
        Name = "Addison Road";
        Type = 1;
    };
    Anacostia =         {
        Code = F06;
        Lat = "38.8629631168";
        Line = GR;
        Lon = "-76.9953707387";
        Name = Anacostia;
        Type = 1;
    };
    Archives =         {
        Code = F02;
        Lat = "38.8936652235";
        Line = GR;
        Lon = "-77.0219143879";
        Name = Archives;
        Type = 1;
    };
};
```

}

I have tried to convert it to an array:

`NSArray *array = [dictionary allValues];`

But I end up with one item in the array, where I want three. How do I do this?

UPDATE: AS requested, here is my current code snip.

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {

    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        NSLog(@"session isSupported...");
        self.session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        self.session.delegate = self;
        [self.session activateSession];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documents = [directories firstObject];

        pathString = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favorites.plist"];
        NSLog(@"pathString > %@", pathString);

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: pathString]) //4
        {
            NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Favorites" ofType:@"plist"];

            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: pathString error:&error];
        }

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathString]) {
            [self readFromFile:pathString];
            NSMutableDictionary  *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathString];
            //NSLog(@" count: %lu", (unsigned long)dictionary.count);
            NSLog(@" dictionary: %@", dictionary);

            NSArray *tempArray = [dictionary allValues];
            self.workingArray = [tempArray mutableCopy];

            [self configureTable];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code. Also what you want to end up with. What you have is a dictionary with three *entries* named "item1", "item2" and "item3" each of which is a dictionary..

Comment: Your listing of the dictionary is incomplete -- you omitted the leading and trailing `{ }` characters, and they are critically important to understanding it.

Comment: @zaph - See John Martin's answer -- the dictionary only contains one entry.

Comment: And you were downvoted for not including code, not including the result you are getting, and failing to include *all* of the source data.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: OK. understand. Thanks for the explanation. I'll post better next time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three values are under a key called "StationFavourites.plist"

So try something like:

```
[(NSDictionary *)dictionary[@"StationFavourites.plist"] allValues];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
        NSDictionary *currDict = dictionary[key];
       // you can create here from the valueDict a new Object and store it for example in an Array
 }
```